# Clang++ Control Flow Integrity with shared_ptr crashes

Tags: c++, clang++

I'm trying to get [control flow integrity](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ControlFlowIntegrity.html) to work with clang++ but I can't get the following code to run:

```cpp
#include <memory>

struct X {
    X() {}
    virtual ~X() {};
};

int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<X> _asd = std::make_shared<X>();
    return 0;
}
```

If I compile and run this with

```sh
clang++ -fsanitize=cfi -fvisibility=hidden -flto -O2 -std=c++14 test.cpp
./a.out
```

the compiled program outputs:

```
[1]    45850 illegal hardware instruction (core dumped)  ./a.out
```

The resulting program crashes inside the `make_shared` function call - inside the standard library.

## Some observations

When I make the destructor non-virtual it terminates successfully, so I initially thought it had something to do with `cfi-vcall` but it works flawlessly with the `-fsanitize=cfi-vcall` option.

The responsible compile flag seems to be `-fsanitize=cfi-unrelated-cast` - with all other available checks the application runs properly.

Looking at the disassembly it seems that the application is calling `~X()` within make_shared (see also Additional Info below)?

[image: unsure what's happening here]

## Questions

Is this a programming mistake? Is it in the compiler, standard library or in my code?

Is there a workaround to make it compile and run with CFI enabled?

Thanks a lot in advance!

## Additional Info

here's the context ([gef](https://gef.readthedocs.io/en/master/)) one instruction before the invalid [`ud1`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ud) instruction.

`[rbx+0x10]` that `rax` is compared to is just zeros:

```
gef➤  x/1g $rbx + 0x10
0x557ec94ffec0: 0x0000000000000000
```

[image: stack trace and surrounding code]

[image: 1 instruction before ud1 instruction]

Comment: How does assembly look like?

Comment: Let me add that to the question

Comment: @user3840170 are the images alright, or would you prefer text? Should I obtain the assembly in a different way?

Comment: Reproducible here, I think https://godbolt.org/z/rWohM9zcs - The 132 exit code is indicative of a SIGILL

Comment: @cisnjxqu IMO you should report a bug.

Comment: I was unable to reproduce using `clang version 13.0.0` (using real **clang**, not my *Frankenstein's monster* clang) on x86_64 architecture.

Comment: @Eljay what OS are you running on? I tried it with Arch & Ubuntu and in both cases the program crashes.

Comment: I tried on macOS 11.6 Big Sur (Darwin 20.6.0).  I have a custom Linux box and a custom Darwin box -- but they're not handy at the moment, and they're a bit experimental.  (And I should probably just mow them over and start fresh since the experiment was cancelled over a year ago.)

Comment: @Eljay Just to make sure - you did run the program and not just the compiler? I realize now that my question could be misunderstood into thinking that the compiler crashes.

Comment: Yes, I also ran the resulting executable.  The **clang** compiler was one that I had built myself and had none of my modifications.  (I've a different clang that I've modified.)

Comment: Do you know the commit hash of your clang version?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239679/discussion-between-eljay-and-cisnjxqu).